# Stretch isolated cells or <td> to max width of table

Tags: html, css

I was trying to achieve the following table,
[image]

using php as follows

```
<?php
while($rowcustomer = mysql_fetch_array($querycustomer)){
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #CC3300;"><h2>'.$rowcustomer['cusname'].'</h2></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #CC3300;"><h2>'.$rowcustomer['cusname'].'</h2></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr height="20">
    <td width="120" height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h3>Invoice Date</h3></td>
    <td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h3 align="center">Invoice Number</h3></td>
    <td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h3 align="center">Invoice Amount</h3></td>
    <td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h3 align="center">Payed Amount</h3></td></tr>';
}           
?>
```

But I get the following
[image]

instead of what I need, how can I achieve it?

Comment: please post the actual code you have, the code you posted can't produce such a result.

Comment: No need to keep this downvoted any longer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer, add `colspan="4"` to the `td` that spans all the columns:

HTML

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #CC3300;" colspan="4">
```

Longer answer :) - Let's clean up some HTML:

Example fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/ssP7W/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Header2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
            <th>Invoice Amount</th>
            <th>Payed Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS - add extra styles and ditch the  `width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"`

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: No worries :) - look into styling your tables with CSS as this will simplify maintenance and maintain a consistent feel. There are lots of good examples out there - [here is one simple demo](http://www.aloud.es/demo/tablezebra/)